# Running gradle task failed after very long time

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, android-emulator

I tried to run my first flutter project but i keep getting this error.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4170314; received: 2359280
  >   Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 5248142; received: 4456416
  >   Could not download protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.5.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.5.0/protos-26.5.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 3432065; received: 2359280
  >   Could not download kotlin-stdlib-common.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.50)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar'.
  >   Read timed out
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20m 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

---

[Screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oambI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used free vpn proxy like hotspot shield.. For some reason i guess in your area those links are blocked unfortunately and unexpectedly.. like in my area.. so please use any free vpn and update your packages again..

If that problem still occurs then  I think you are trying to create an android project in a flutter project.

Usually android studio shows a pop up box for that. Which you should not click okay..

if this is not the problem can you please clarify bit more? shuch from where you have get the project and what have you done before it was doing all the updates?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I thought of downloading a new image(API 28). 
Before using VPN and it worked.

I think the problem was version conflict, previously I was using API 27 (OREO).

Comment: oww.. yeah even that might be the case..also